# Как в aiogram в callback handler обработать один из нескольких возможных запросов?

Tags: python, aiogram

Как должно работать:

1. Выводится сообщение с двумя инлайн кнопками
2. Пользователь нажимает одну из них
3. Сообщение удаляется
4. В зависимости какую кнопку он нажал, срабатывает внутри function1 одно из условий и отправляется определённое сообщение, что уже не суть важно для вопроса

Изначально я думал что всё будет прекрасно работать с таким кодом:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text = 'button2' or 'button3')
async def process_callback_button23(c_q: types.CallbackQuery):
    t1 = c_q.data
    await c_q.answer()
    await c_q.message.delete()
    await function1(t1)
```

Но бот не воспринимает `callback_data = 'button3'`. То есть, если я нажму первую инлайн кнопку, которая отправляет `callback_data = 'button2'`, то `process_callback_button23` срабатывает, а если нажму вторую, которая отправляет `callback_data = 'button3'`, то process_callback_button23 не реагирует вообще.

Создавать для каждой кнопки отдельный handler я не захотел, т.к. действие, по сути, одно и тоже, мне главное передать в function1 то, какую кнопку нажал пользователь.

Вопрос в целом, такой же как и в заголовке: 'Как в callback handler обработать один из нескольких возможных запросов?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="button")
#Или так
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data=="button2" or call.data=="button3")
```

Comment: Подошёл 2 способ, спасибо), единственное, он воспринимает func, как фильтр, поэтому я просто на строчку выше вывел "func=lambda call: call.data=="button2" or call.data=="button3"", а handler оставил таким: @dp.callback_query_handler(func)

Comment: Мой косяк, можно убрать func